# Android USB debugging - computer can not find phone

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I was using Android Studio, was debugging on my phone via USB. Now the PC can not find my phone any more. The phone is charging, but the PC can't find it.

I have windows 10. USB debugging is enabled. I tried restarting both the PC and the phone. I tried lots of other things, like USBDeview, PDAnet and so on.

Any ideas what to do or how to find out what's wrong?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Comment: try with some other usb cable many a times some usb cables only charge the phone and do not work for usb debugging

Comment: In your android studio try to check and uncheck adb integration from ,Go To " Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration" . If that also doesn't work then go to "Run->attach debugger to android process" .

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal call "adb kill-server". It should cause a restart of adb.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it that for Xamarin. And did it before for Android Studio.

You need to:

-- Install drivers for your phone and your SO.

-- Install Google USB Drivers (open Android SDK Manager).

-- Connect your phone by USB and wait until your computer recognize it.

When you will try to run or debug your app you can choice the device (virtual or physical) where you can do it.

**Note**: If you don´t run any app before, maybe you will need to install a few API (by Android SDK Manager), for compiling the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack that worked for me . Once your device is connected to the PC click on the notification in your android device that says 
**Connected as a media device** it will take you to the **USB Computer connection** screen and select the Connect as option as **Camera(PTP)**.
I hope that it helps.